# Web page interfacing with COM port to control page

Tags: c#, php, javascript, asp.net

I'm looking at creating a project that has a touch screen panel on a com port and a front facing website.

I want the touch screen panel to interface with the web page, it will have two buttons (left & right) and I want those actions to "do something" on the web page.

I'm trying to work out which programming/scripting language would be best to, I could use JS but I believe that'd mean polling a c/perl/php script that is listening on the COM port considering JS has no socket capabilities.

Would it be easier if I used ASP.NET/C# - would it cause me less headaches?

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing, if I understand the question correctly, would be to get a driver for the touchscreen that emulates a mouse. Then you don't need to do anyhing with sockets.

Comment: Its not a touch screen, sorry - its a touch panel with just two buttons.

Comment: I chose to go with creating a C# or C++ application that constantly monitors the COM port and then converts the return result into key presses using SendKeys (C#) or CSendKeys (C++). That way, I can use JS to pick up the keystrokes and deal with it that way.